# How to set `rpath` with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

I have an executable that uses some shared objects.
These shared objects have other shared objects as dependencies, and I want to set my main executable's `rpath` to include the directories for those dependencies, since `runpath` is not used for indirect dependencies.

I'm trying to bake `rpath` into my ELF, however when using this:
`gcc -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp -lstdc++ -L./lib -Wl,-rpath,./lib`

The result is that `./lib` is set in the ELF as `RUNPATH` and not `RPATH`:

```bash
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [./lib]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x1000
 ...
```

Can someone explain why this happens? I was expecting `./lib` to be defined in the `RPATH` section and not `RUNPATH`. Seems like `RPATH` section does not exist at all.

I am using `gcc` version `11.1.0`, with `ld` version `2.34`.

I know this might not be the best solution for managing indirect dependencies and I'd be happy to hear a better one, however I still wonder why `-Wl,-rpath,./lib` results in `RUNPATH` defined in the ELF, and not `RPATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a DT_RUNPATH entry you need `--enable-new-dtags`.

To get a DT_RPATH entry (which is deprecated) you need `--disable-new-dtags`.

In your case, something like this:

```
gcc -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp -lstdc++ -L./lib -Wl,--disable-new-dtags,-rpath,./lib
```

I'll suggest to use an absolute path with rpath, I'm not sure from which directory relative paths are interpreted. There is also `$ORIGIN` if you want to use the executable as reference point.

See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html for more informations.

Comment: Still defined as `RUNPATH`...
Regarding the relative path, it's just for the example but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I mistakenly inverted the relation  to get a `DT_RPATH` you need  `--disable-new-dtags`, to get `DT_RUNPATH`, `--enable-new-dtags`.

Comment: Nice, that worked! Can you elaborate maybe on what `new-dtags` mean?